# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError on virtual column in class without attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, activemodel

I want to pass a .xlsx tempfile from a form to the import model. However, I'm running into `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`. I correctly defined strong parameters, but there might be a peculiarity when dealing with virtual columns for classes without attributes.

The model logic works when pointing to a local file path, so I left most of it out. Here's my code:

`new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @package_import do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :file %>
  <%= f.submit "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

`package_imports_controller.rb`

```
class PackageImportsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @package_import = PackageImport.new
  end

  def create
    @package_import = PackageImport.new(params[:package_import])
    if @package_import.save
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Imported packages"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

private

    def package_import_params
        params.require(:package_import).permit(:file)
    end

end
```

`package_import.rb`

```
class PackageImport 
include ActiveModel::Model 
...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `params[:package_import]` to `package_import_params` in `@package_import = PackageImport.new(params[:package_import])` of your `create` method.

```
def create
  @package_import = PackageImport.new(package_import_params)

  if @package_import.save
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Imported packages"
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: This was a step in the right direction. Because :file is a virtual attribute, I also had to add `attr_accessor :file` to the model to make it work as expected.